# HTML element being destroyed and rebuilt, event handler not added

Tags: javascript, html, performance, reactjs

I don't have the full code for this..

```
render() {
    return {
     html is here and rebuilt via some other method(it is imported)
     <html react-id="someelement" onClick={ eventHandler }></html>
    }
}
```

The eventHandler is not attached after the html is rebuilt(which is every 300ms). Not sure why they are rebuilding the html I heard it was due to styling!

Anyhow, i can use

```
componentDidMount() {
   getElById("someelement").addEventListener("click", eventHandler )
}
```

But, this causes a re-render of the element. Which is inefficient imo, as we don't see the need to re-render due to HTML

Is there another way? One that won't need to re-render the react components?

Comment: Can you show the whole component? I think the problem has to do with how you're assigning the onClick (how you did it here won't work) but without the actual JSX I'm not sure if that's what you're actually doing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply Ben, that was actually not how it was implemented, it was onClick = { this.eventHandler }